# visiting mom from Romania to Canada

Tags: customs-and-immigration, canada, language-barrier, romanian-citizens

Anybody from Canada here? My mom ( 90 years old) wants to visit us in Canada, the only problem is that she does not speak any other languages except Romanian. Do they have translators at the airport? My worries are related to the Customs declaration form, that now is on mandatory on the Primary Inspection Kiosks, a too complicated computerized system for somebody that old with no computer knowledge...

Comment: Could you try talking her through completing the form before she travels? Eg there are guides online https://youtu.be/qrRJGZ_A65U?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, and yes, I did think of that, and we will do it on Skype, but she has Parkinson as well, and her hands are shaking....

Comment: Does your mom need a visa to visit you? If so, one eligibility criteria is that she needs to be in good health; at 90 they may ask her to undergo a medical exam https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/visit-canada/eligibility.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Language problems at the airport?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/24980/language-problems-at-the-airport)

Comment: @ Traveler : My mom does not need a visa, therefore no medical requirements for a short visit

Comment: @ Kate Gregory: thank you, I looked at the other thread you suggested, however that Mom was travelling within Europe, hence other requirements ( much more simpler than the Canadian ones)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend that your Mom, writes a letter stating:

- She can't speak Canadian but can speak Romanian
- Answers all fields on the custom form

If need be they will obtain a translator at the airport.

Comment: Last I checked, they spoke English and French in Canada officially, plus a smattering of native languages, but not Canadian... ;)

Comment: Canadian English is spoken in Canada :)

Comment: May I suggest that you provide her with a letter in English explaining the purpose of her trip, details of you/your family and your contact phone numbers and explaining that your mum doesn't speak English. A copy of her return ticket is a good idea as well as details of her travel insurance to demonstrate that she won't need access to public funds' (Canada health care).